# Dropping Users from SQL Server Database via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I am trying to drop users from a SQL server database via PowerShell using the following code:

```
$sql_server = "mysqlserver"
$dbname = "mydb"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server")($sql_server)
$db = $server.Databases["$dbname"]
$logins = $db.users

if ($logins.count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($login in $logins) {
        if ($login -notmatch "\[dbo\]|\[guest\]|\[INFORMATION_SCHEMA\]|\[sys\]") {
            $user = $login -replace '[^a-zA-Z\.\\]'
            write-host "Dropping $user"
            $db.Users[$user].Drop();
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting an error stating:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>   +         foreach ($login in $logins) {
>   +                  ~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException

I think its saying that `$logins` is being changed because I'm deleting users? I'm not sure how to work around that though?

---

***EDIT***

---

The following should work. Thanks to @Neil Hibbert for the help.

```
$sql_server = "mysqlserver"
$dbname = "mydb"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server")($sql_server)
$db = $server.Databases["$dbname"]
$logins = $db.users

if ($logins.count -gt 0) {
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $logins.count; $i++) {
        if ($logins[$i] -notmatch "\[dbo\]|\[guest\]|\[INFORMATION_SCHEMA\]|\[sys\]") {
            $user = $logins[$i] -replace '[^a-zA-Z\.\\]'
            write-host "Dropping $user"
            $db.Users[$user].Drop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more of a .NET thing. Whilst iterating over collections with a foreach-loop, individual elements may not be modified, which is what you are trying to do. If you replaced the foreach loop with a for-loop and tried the same action, it should work out successful.

Comment: Not sure how I can change this to a for loop? I tried   for ($i=0; $i -lt $logins.count; $i++) {
   if ($login[$i] -notmatch "\[dbo\]|\[guest\]|\[INFORMATION_SCHEMA\]|\[sys\]") {
    $user = $login[$i] -replace '[^a-zA-Z\.\\]'
    write-host "Dropping $user"
    $logins[$i].Drop();
   }
  } but that didn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify, your comment code is slightly different than your code snippet in that your comment code reads '$logins[$i].Drop()' rather than '$db.Users[$user].Drop()' is this just a typo or the code you ran in your script?

Comment: I've tried both - just trying to get it to work.

Comment: Switching it to $db.Users[$user].Drop() results in "Cannot index into a null array on if ($login[$i] -notmatch "\[dbo\]|\[guest\]|\[INFORMATION_SCHEMA\]|\[sys\]")"

Comment: ok, if you initialize $logins with $server.Logins rather than $db.users, and then check $db.Users.Contains($login) and call $db.Users[$login].Drop(), what happens then?

Comment: @Neilhibbert your solution/suggestion works its just my inability to differentiate between logIN vs logON vs login (singular) vs logins (plural). If you want to copy paste the above code as the solution I will give you credit. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain the error message you are/were seeing is because you had set $logins to the list of $db.users and then tried to delete a user during the foreach loop.

Initializing $logins with $server.Logins (rather than $db.users) and then checking $db.Users.Contains($login) before calling $db.Users[$login].Drop() in your loop will fix your issue...