# Delete manage identity user from sql

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I have situation here, I have enabled system assigned manage identity of Azure WebApp. And created the External Provide user in Azure SQL database.
These are combination of Powershell task and Dynamic SQL in devops release pipeline

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
```

These works fine
But, for testing purpose I have Deleted Azure Web App, but its entry in sql is still persisted
So I tried to Drop this User via powershell task in devops.
But its now allowing me to do so.

If situation is unclear please let me know I will make necessory changes in it.

Comment: Why don't run the `DROP USER user_name` command in SSMS? That's the most directly way.

Comment: @Leon Yue, that needs to be an automated process

Comment: can this blog give you any ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567793/dropping-users-from-sql-server-database-via-powershell?

Comment: Hello @AstroBoy, did you solve the problem now?